# How can I make a post virtualenv hook in pyenv to upgrade pip packages

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I am using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage different Python versions on my machine, and [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) to manage my venvs. When I create a new venv with something like `pyenv virtualenv foo` it doesn't install the latest version of `pip`, `setuptools`, and `wheel` into the venv. I would like to run `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` inside each venv after it has been created.

[pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) has the concept of hooks for before and after a command. I am able to run this command by adding the following file

`~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/etc/pyenv.d/virtualenv/after.bash`

with the following contents

```
after_virtualenv 'pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel'
```

The command is run, but it is not run inside the venv, so it just uses the current `pip`. How can I call this command inside the venv in the after_virtualenv hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I figured it out you can just specify just created virtualenv name as the  PYENV_VERSION and call `pyenv-exec`.

```
upgrade_packages() {
  PYENV_VERSION=$VIRTUALENV_NAME pyenv-exec pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
}

after_virtualenv 'upgrade_packages'
```